# Cannot select ListView item when clicking on some parts

Tags: wpf, listview

I create a `ListView` having a `GridView` like below:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOrder}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListViewItem}}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                                <Border BorderBrush="SteelBlue" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="Border" Padding="10">
                                    <GridViewRowPresenter />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"></Setter>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance entities:ExecReport}">
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Symbol" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Instrument.Symbol}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Side" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Side}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Price" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Price}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Total Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Qty}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Open Size" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OpenQty}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding State}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Validity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Validity}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Order Seq" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OrderSeq}" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I can select items by clicking on them in most places. But when I click on some places they do not get selected. The backing field is not set either. This problem does not happen if I remove the `ListViewItem` Style.

The below image points out the sort of place where an item does not get selected.

How do I fix this?

[image: selection problem]

Comment: You must have missed something from default template of ListViewItem in your overriden template.

Comment: Replace GridViewRowPresenter With <ContentPresenter/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Background property of your Border(named "Border") to Transparent. Since controls without background will be considered as hollow and hit test may not be possible. More information on [HitTesting](http://agsmith.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/hit-testing-in-wpf/).

Comment: Yep. This fixes it. I tried `IsHitTestVisible="False"` earlier on the border but didn't work. But this does. Thanks